# Hide a word within a class with just CSS

Tags: html, css

A WordPresss site, where I'm attempting to hide the word 'SKU' as seen below in the html code.

Here is the html

```
<div class="card-body card-body">
                <h3><a href="https://www.staging4.XXXX/shop/resources/phase-1-phonics-planning-week-1-example-test-free/">Phase 1 Phonics Planning Week 1 Example TEST FREE</a></h3>
                <p><small><strong>SKU:</strong> </small></p>
                <p>
              </p></div>
```

I want to use a just CSS to hide the SKU word, my effort thus far, but I'm unable to see how to target just SKU, I presume I need to use the  element some how?:

CSS

```
.card .card-body {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: Target the element wrapping the text...which, here, is the `strong`.

Comment: Of course, you can't target *specific text* in CSS.

Comment: Not sure why someone felt the need to mark the question down! If you are going to do so, leave a reason why.

Comment: I'd assume for lack of research...this would be simple enough to find with a cursory search.

Comment: I researched via Google and found nothing that met my complete requirement.\

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unless im misunderstanding your question, you can just use:

```
.card-body p small strong {display:none}
```

If this isn't what you require please elaborate.

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of ways. One is to use

```
.card-body small {
    display: none;
}
```

But, it would probably be better to create a new class just for hidden things, like this

```
.hide-sku {
    display: none;
}
```

and in the html

`<span class='hide-sku'>SKU:</span>`

(also, you have the class `card-body` duplicated -- not sure if that's your intention)

Answer (score 1):

If you *can* control classes in your html code - the easiest way is to add some helper class:

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="card-body">
  <h3>
    <a href="#">Phase 1 Phonics Planning Week 1 Example TEST FREE</a>
  </h3>
  <p class="hidden">
    <small>
      <strong>SKU:</strong> 
    </small>
  </p>
  <p>Some other content</p>
</div>
```

If you *can't* control classes and change html code - you can use `:nth-of-type` or `:nth-child` pseudoclasses:

```css
.card-body p:nth-of-type(1) {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="card-body">
  <h3>
    <a href="#">Phase 1 Phonics Planning Week 1 Example TEST FREE</a>
  </h3>
  <p>
    <small>
      <strong>SKU:</strong> 
    </small>
  </p>
  <p>Some other content</p>
</div>
```